# MySQL Select User IDs based on Continuously Rows Value & condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Table with

- row_id (primary)
- user_id
- user_ip
- date_start (unix timestamp)
- date_end (unix timestamp)

I want to select just the User IDs of this table (distinct) **IF** **there are at least 2 continuously rows WHERE**

> the user_ip in [row X] is different with the user_ip in [row X+1]

**AND**

> ABS( date_end in [row X]  - date_start in [row X+1] ) <= 20

The Rows should be ordered by row_id ASC so that we can get the row X, X+1 and so on continuously.

I did this with PHP easily, but it's very very slow so i think it can be done with just using sql.

**EXAMPLE**

```
row_id  |  user_id  |  user_ip   |  date_start  |  date_end

1       ,  1        ,  127.0.0.1 ,  1469100096  ,  1469100099
2       ,  2        ,  5.5.5.5   ,  1469100054  ,  1469100055
3       ,  3        ,  4.4.4.4   ,  1469100032  ,  1469100036
4       ,  1        ,  6.6.6.6   ,  1469100117  ,  1469100099
5       ,  4        ,  127.0.0.1 ,  1469100001  ,  1469100005
6       ,  2        ,  127.0.0.1 ,  1469100555  ,  1469100565
```

From this , we should get just the User ID 1 because the user id 1 HAD different IP in 2 continuously rows + the date_end of the first row (1469100099) - the date start of the next row 1(469100117) = 18 which is <= 20.

We should NOT return the User ID 2, because although it validates the first condition, it doesn't validate the 2nd condition with the date_end and date_start.

Comment: Look at : stackoverflow.com/questions/9824948/… And try something like this:

SELECT parent.id FROM tableName AS parent inner join tableName AS child ON parent.user_ip != child.user_ip and DATE_SUB((parent.date_end -child.date_start), INTERVAL 20 HOUR) and parent.user_id = child.user_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT parent.* FROM userip parent  
                JOIN userip child ON parent.`user_ip` != child.`user_ip`  
                WHERE ABS( parent.`date_end` - child.date_start) <= 20 
                      AND parent.user_id = child.user_id 
GROUP BY parent.user_id
```

Comment: Wouldn't this display the user's ID twice?  All appearances of ID 1 will become parent at some point.  One would be 18 while the other would be -18.  With the ABS both would be 18.  Even without the ABS it be under 20.  The OP asked for distinct (so only once). I am not sure if it would matter to OP but you could say <= 20 and >=0 then get rid of the ABS unless MySQL wouldn't like that.

Comment: I think we are only concerned about userids, so grouping them with userid will only make them appear once. You are right child may again become parent and condition can be true again, which can make the user appear once more. So unless we want to look for each true conditions for a user, grouping will work

Comment: Right.  I completely forgot about the GROUP BY you had at the end.  Was too focused on the rest of it : )

Comment: Well, for some reason is very slow. I have ~1.000.000 rows in the table and it takes like forever

Comment: Can you post the complete schema with primary keys and indexes. Also you can run explain command to see where it is running slow http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html